# Unable to change the length of a global 2D storage array

Tags: truffle, remix, testrpc, arrays, state-variable

I am facing difficulties changing the length of a global 2D storage array.

It seems to be working correctly on [Remix IDE](https://remix.ethereum.org), but when I try to test it on `ganache-cli` (formerly known as `testrpc`) - either via `truffle test` (Javascript) or via `web3` (Python) - it fails to work.

By "fail to work", I mean I can set the length of the array, but when I retrieve it - I always get 0.

Here is a minimal piece of code which reproduces the problem:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Test {
    struct Data {
        uint256 a;
        uint256 b;
        uint256 c;
        uint256 d;
        uint256 e;
        uint256 f;
    }

    Data[][] private lists;

    function Test() public {
    }

    function setLength(uint256 length) public {
        lists.length = length;
    }

    function getLength() public constant returns (uint256) {
        return lists.length;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am using a storage array.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

This problem stems not from changing the length of an array, but rather from changing the state of the contract (i.e., changing a global variable).

So far, I have only tested functions which do not change the state of the contract - either via `truffle` (Javascript) or via `web3` (Python).

In both cases, I have been using `call` in order to execute the Solidity function.

For functions which **do** change the state of the contract, one needs to use `transact` instead.

The full explanation can be found in [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/34182/16043).